# Why do $H$ and $L^2$ commute in spherically symmetric potential?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, hamiltonian

In [this PDF document (a lecture by Shivaly Reddy, page 13)](http://users.ece.gatech.edu/~alan/ECE6451/Lectures/StudentLectures/Reddy_3p1_AngMomNcentralForces.pdf), he says that

> $L^2$ is independent of $r$; therefore it commutes with any function of $r$.

This seems related to a problem in [Schaum's Quantum Mechanics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0071623582) (Amazon link) dealing with a particle in a spherical potential well.  In the solution, after writing down the Hamiltonian, they say,

> It is evident that $[H, L^2] = 0$;  hence, we write $\Psi = R(r) \cdot Y_{ml}(\theta,\varphi)$..."

1. Both sources seem to be saying that when the potential well is
    spherically symmetric, $[H, L^2] = 0$.  Why, exactly?
2. Schaum goes on to say that since $[H,L^2] = 0$, then we can separate
    out the radial and angular parts of the wave function.  Would you
    please explain that reasoning also?

Comment: qest 1: it's well detailled from page 13 last paragraph until the line preceding the conclusion in the middle of the next page ( impossible copy paste )

Comment: He says  "An operator can commute with another independent operator"  by which I think he means that if one operator depends only on certain variables, and another operator depends only on different variables, then they commute.  L^2 depends on θ,φ only and Kinetic Energy depends on r only, thus they commute.

Comment: Basically I think if you have two operators that depend on different variables in this way, if you expand out the expression for the two different order of operations  (for example, (L^2)*(KE) and (KE)*(L^2))  basically you get a long sum of various products.  But all these products can be rearranged to look like the other order of operation's products because  "anything on the inside of a derivative of θ that depends only on φ or r can come out of the derivative", and similarly for derivatives of φ and r.

Comment: So I am basically saying you can take partial derivatives in any order.  I now read that one can only switch around the order of partial derivatives in this way if the partial derivative(s) of Ψ are continuous.  (http://www.mhhe.com/math/calc/smithminton2e/cd/folder_structure/text/chap12/section03.htm about 2/3rds the way down)  So I guess it's often glossed over that wave functions are continuous when differentiated with respect to r,θ,φ.  (They are, right?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess mark this question as answered, though not fully.
See the comments posted on the question itself.

--

(7/31/2015)  In the
https://faculty.washington.edu/seattle/physics227/reading/reading-26-27.pdf
document, they
write the Hamiltonian = $(-\hbar^2 / (2m)) [d^2/dr^2
+ (2/r)(d/dr) - \hat{L^2}/(r^2 \hbar^2)] + V(r)$.  Then
if you expand the expression $[\hat{H},\hat{L^2}]$, and
use the fact that you can swap the order of partial derivatives
because $\hat{L^2}$ is a function of $\theta, \phi$ only,
it all cancels out to 0.

--

(7/31/2015)  They also answer the question of why we know we can
separate $\psi = R(r)Y(\theta,\phi)$:

"An often asked question is  'How do you know you can assume that?'
You do not know.  You assume it, and if it works, you have found a
solution.  If it does not work, you need to attempt other methods or
techniques.  Here, it will work."

Comment: This is not an answer though.

Comment: https://faculty.washington.edu/seattle/physics227/reading/reading-26-27.pdf seems like it may have a worked out proof of $[\hat{H}, \hat{L^2}] = 0$

Comment: You should then add the results in your answer for future reference. You can edit your answer by clicking the *edit* button.